# ActiveRecord::Reflections Adding personal meta data to Reflection

Tags: activerecord, metadata, activemodel

Hi I have the following model

```
class Tale < ActiveRecord::Base #TODO model should be created automatically based on the structure

attr_accessor :sex, :family, :me

after_initialize do
@sex = nil
@family = []
@me = []
end

  before_create do
self.joined = false
true
end

 has_many :tale_culture_joins
 has_many :tale_purpose_joins
 has_many :tale_book_joins
 has_many :tale_keyword_joins
 has_many :tale_character_joins
 has_many :tale_moral_joins
 has_many :tale_event_joins

 #TODO Grouping models with a unique single identifier that can be searched for as tag. Like these are associations for searching
 #TODO need to fix so that on query only uniq results are returned ... can be added @runtime
has_many :cultures, through: :tale_culture_joins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :purposes, through: :tale_purpose_joins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :books, through: :tale_book_joins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :keywords, through: :tale_keyword_joins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :characters, through: :tale_character_joins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :morals, through: :tale_moral_joins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :values, through: :morals

has_many :events, through: :tale_event_joins, dependent: :destroy

has_many :hyperlinks
has_many :content_types, through: :hyperlinks

end
```

Some of the reflections are used to get and post data from a form.
As can be seen values is related to tales through morals. However I will not be storing that in a tale_value join table.

I perform data entry and search functions.  want to define certain reflections for only search. How can I add a tag | meta data | key to a reflection that I can later check on

For example on the has_many :values, through: : morals I would like to add option :searchable .. this is for me then when i am building the search interface I want to query those reflections that have searchable as a tag.